# Web API response time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm building a server monitoring system and want to send a request to a Web API and get the server's health in a JSON object if it's ok, if its database connections are working, its response time, etc.

How can I implement the response time, saying how long the Web API takes to answer the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start a [Stopwatch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx) on your client and stop it when you recive your awnser

Comment: Yeah, it makes sense to do it client side. Thanks. :)

Comment: You are welcome ;-) Sometimes the simple things are the best^^

Answer (score 11):

If you want to implement Web Api Monitoring, you can create a custom DelegatingHandler to track action duration and status.

Here is a very basic example to measure operation duration. The duration is added to response (quite useless) ; it's better to store this kind of data to a dedicated repository.

```
public class MonitoringDelegate : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var watcher = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var response = await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
        watcher.Stop();

        //store duration somewheren here in the response header
        response.Headers.Add("X-Duration", watcher.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

        return response;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but it makes most sense to me to do this client side. :) After all, that response time is the one who matters.

Comment: yes and no. If your client have slowdowns, it's already too late. using  a DelegatingHandler allow to you to store timings somewhere and to be pro-active on performance issues.

Comment: How can I use your solution in .net core?