# Azure get APIs response time

Tags: asp.net, azure

I have an `ASP.NET WebApi` project deployed on Azure, and I am looking for a report/analytics that tells me the response times of the APIs/services. I want to identify the slow APIs. Is there any kind of reporting in Azure that identifies the response times of APIs or the slow APIs? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for [Application Insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/application-insights/). Read [Find and diagnose performance issues with Azure Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-tutorial-performance)

Here is the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/quick-monitor-portal) to enable Application Insights in an ASP.NET Web Application.

Comment: @AliShahzad  Did you have run the WebApi in debug mode?

Comment: @JanleyZhang how can I debug on Azure? Please guide.

Answer (score 1):

> how can I debug on Azure? Please guide.

1. In publish settings>choose **debug** mode to publish your webapi project to Azure.
   Then visit the api method to trigger app insights.

[image]

2. In Server Explorer in Visual Studio, right click web app name>choose attach debugger. You could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-dotnet-troubleshoot-visual-studio).

[image]

The result in app insight in Azure web app:

[image]

> I don't want to change my production app to run in debug mode

You could also use **Stopwatch** class to measure the response time in web api method. Please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724844/web-api-response-time).

Comment: I don't want to change my production app to run in debug mode. I just want to collect stats for slow APIs. Can I do without changing to debug mode?

Comment: App insight is triggered in debug mode. If you want to use app insights to monitor the performance for your web api project, you need to run this mode.

Comment: @AliShahzad  In this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-asp-net), you could see the step2:"Run your app with F5. Open different pages to generate some telemetry".

Comment: @AliShahzad Or you could try to use [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class to measure the response time in each api method. Please refer to this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23724844/web-api-response-time).

Comment: Yes this can be a better option than to run app in debug mode.